# Azure Vm Backup - change from OS Disk only to all disks

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-backup-vault

I have a virtual machine that has a backup that only includes the OS Disk.
I need to change this so it includes all disks on the vm.

[image]

I cannot find where to do this on the Recovery Vault or the Backup Policy.
I have only found documentation that is for excluding drives from the Backup Policy, not adding them.

Is it possible to add all the drives of a vm to an existing backup policy?

(Apologies, I am fairly new to azure and the vm backups so I am not sure if my terminology is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***[`az backup protection update-for-vm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/backup/protection?view=azure-cli-latest#az_backup_protection_update_for_vm)*** with include as well the same way exclude works.

**For excluding disk:**

```
az backup protection update-for-vm --resource-group {resourcegroupname} --vault-name {vaultname} -c {vmname} -i {vmname} --disk-list-setting exclude --diskslist {LUN no's separated by space}
```

**For including disks:**

```
az backup protection update-for-vm --resource-group {resourcegroupname} --vault-name {vaultname} -c {vmname} -i {vmname} --disk-list-setting include --diskslist {LUN no's separated by space}
```

***Example:***

**I have a VM with 2 data disks as below:**

[image]

**My Backup excludes the 2 data disks:**

[image]

**Command to include the data disks:**

```
az backup protection update-for-vm --resource-group myresourcegroup --vault-name vault131 -c ansumantestvm -i ansumantestvm --disk-list-setting include --diskslist 0 1
```

**After running the command the output is as :**

[image]

[image]

**Note :** [Reference on How to Install azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#install)